# How can i create model to match nested geometric image with child geometric images

Tags: machine-learning-model, image-recognition, image-preprocessing

[image][image]image1 is a nesting file and image2 is child file ,i want to find child file is contain in nesting file or not.We tried using random forest but it did not work.can you suggest some good image matching algorithm?

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the code you've tried so far, even if it does not yet produce the desired results.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the task? This relationship between child image and nesting file is similar on all samples? Scale, position vary a lot? There are cases where the child is rotated in the nesting file?

Comment: There is no similar relationship between  child and nesting file.Only position can  changed. There are cases where the child part is rotated in the nesting file